# How to extract person's last name from Wikidata database?

Tags: data-extraction, structured-data, wikidata

Here is the page for Albert Einstein in Wikidata:

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q937

I can't see any property for his last name (which is "Einstein") here and do you?

How to extract person's last name from this database?

Answer (score 3):

On Wikidata, to extract a person's family name, you have to look for an item's statements which are using property [`P734` (*Family Name*)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P734). `P734` is a property only allowing values pointing to other items. So the statement's value will be another item, representing the family name. The family name as a string can then be extracted from that item's label.

In the case of [`Q937` (*Albert Einstein*)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q937), the family name is [`Q16834800` (*Einstein*)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q16834800).

Comment: To reduce your confusion; There was no statement for a family name on `Q937` (*Albert Einstein*) until a few minutes before I wrote this answer. As Wikidata is a collaborative knowledge base where everyone can edit, I just added that information.